# How to have conditional statements in "linked" method calls?

Tags: javascript

Is there a cleaner way of writing this code? It's only the `.trim()` statement that differs.

```
if (imageOptions.trim) {
    // Trim
    gm(imageBuffer, 'image.' + imageOptions.imageFormat)
        .gravity(imageOptions.gravity)
        .resize(imageOptions.imageWidth, imageOptions.imageHeight, '^')
        .crop(imageOptions.imageWidth, imageOptions.imageHeight)
        .trim()
        .toBuffer(imageOptions.imageFormat.toUpperCase(), callback);
}
else {
    // No trim
    gm(imageBuffer, 'image.' + imageOptions.imageFormat)
        .gravity(imageOptions.gravity)
        .resize(imageOptions.imageWidth, imageOptions.imageHeight, '^')
        .crop(imageOptions.imageWidth, imageOptions.imageHeight)
        .toBuffer(imageOptions.imageFormat.toUpperCase(), callback);
}
```

Bonus question: what's the proper terminology for these "linked" method calls?

Comment: is `gm` the  GraphicsMagick for node ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes, correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the result of those method calls to a variable and then have a conditional, there's no need to write the entire chain unbroken:

```
var img = gm(...)
            .gravity(..)
            .resize(..)
            .crop(..);

if (imageOptions.trim) {
    img.trim();
}

img.toBuffer(..);
```

And these things are called *chained method calls*.

Comment: It would be safer to store the `img.trim()` to another var and use that for the `.toBuffer()` as you do not know if the `trim` works on the original or returns a new copy (*at least i do not know from the given context*).

Comment: Agreed, that depends on how the library is implemented. Most image libraries I'm familiar with manipulate the object itself instead of returning a new object though.